# How to check if a symbol is resolvable in the current namespace?

Tags: clojure

I want to check if a symbol is resolvable in the current namespace. What's the canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After sifting through the API docs once more, I've stumbled on what might be the appropriate function:

```
; Returns the var or Class to which the symbol
; will be resolved in the current namespace, else nil.
  (resolve 'foo)

; see also:
  (ns-resolve *a-namespace* 'foo)
```

Comment: How do you tell the difference between a symbol that is unbound and a symbol that is bound to nil?

Comment: Only the Var that is named by the symbol can be bound to nil.
The symbol itself either names a Var in the current namespace, then it can be resolved, or not (then resolve returns nil).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this page](http://clojure.org/namespaces). For example

```
(ns-map *ns*)
```

will give you a map of the bindings in the current namespace. You can examine this map to decide if your symbol is a key in the map,

```
(defn resolvable? [sym] 
  (contains? (ns-map *ns*) sym))
```

I do not know if this is the *canonical* way.

Comment: `(contains? (ns-map *ns*) key)` does the same, probably faster.